# clustering large data with ELKI

Tags: memory, subset, hierarchical-clustering, elki

I'm using `ELKI's AnderbergHierarchicalClustering` for my data set with over `150000` observations and for each observation, I'm using three variables: `lat`, `lng` and`price` and all of them are `double`.

I've got following problems:

- my data set is larger than the accepted one (<= 65535 observations)
- this algorithm is also doing a `right shift` for the `Agnes triangle` - `(size * (size - 1)) >>> 1` - this comes to large `RAM` needs

In order to solve this problem, I decided to split the data set into overlapping subsets of `20000 obs`.

For `20000 obs` I shall need `~4.8GB RAM`.

I don't know what would be the best approach for splitting the data in such a way, that the cluster result applied on the subsets  will be as close as possible to the result of clustering the whole set.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `single-linkage`, you can use `SLINK` which only needs `O(n)` memory.

It will still need `O(n^2)` time.

`Hierarchical clustering` is not very scalable.

`CLINK` can do `complete linkage` with `O(n)` memory, but the result quality is usually not very good (usually worse than `Anderberg` with `complete linkage`).

All the other algorithms we have are `O(n^2)` in memory, unfortunately.

Thus at around 65535 instances you will hit a wall with `Java`.

I have one algorithm on my todo list that should be able to run in `O(n log n)` if I'm not mistaken with `index support`. But I did not get around to study it in detail yet - it's not clear which `linkage strategies` it can support besides `single-linkage`.

If you have a lot of *duplicates*, make sure to merge them first!

Comment: I've forgot to say, that I'm using `complete-linkage`. 
I've tried `Anderberg` with other `linkage strategies`, but the `complete-linkage` returns the beste results, for my data.
I do not have duplicates at all.

Comment: Well, you can then try `CLINK`, but I was not convinced of the quality. Complete-linkage clustering just is very expensive.

Comment: I've tried `CLINK`, but I'm not satisfied with the results. I've found a good way to scale the data.

Comment: It may be interesting for future readers if you could share your experience with them.

Comment: I decided to partition my data into overlapping subsets. I'm working with geographical data so it wasn't hard to partition the data, because obvious data from Vienna has nothing to do with data from Innsbruck. So I partitioned the data from east to west and there is a 10% overlapping between the subsets.